# Why is 'you' considered plural?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, grammatical-person

The pronoun 'you' can be used both as a singular and a plural pronoun. However, it is never paired with 'is' and always with 'are'.

Why is it that 'you' is considered plural?

My guess would be that it has something to do with its etymology: perhaps it was derived from a plural form which is why it remains so to this day. However, if anyone has any further clarification that would be greatly helpful.

Comment: It's never used with 'am' either. The conjugation of 'be' is the most irregular one found in English, and has ended up as am///are///is/is/is/is///are///are///are.

Comment: *you is* is widely used, but not widely accepted by the guardians of many of the forms of English encountered around the world.

Comment: Yes, it is plural. Explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction

Answer (score 2):

Edwin Ashworth  rightly  pointed out  you  is  never  followed  by    either    am  or   is.

Strictly  speaking   you  is  plural  and  thou  is  singular.
 Even  singular  they  is  followed  by  a  plural  verb  but   an  indefinite  article.

> **Thou  art  great  my Lord.**
>
> **You  are  a  teacher.**  ( one person)
>
> **You are all  welcome.**( more than  one  person)

**They  are  a  great  teacher**( when  gender is  not  known)

Comment: I think  my  answer  is  downvoted  because  I  have  answered an irrelavent  question?

Comment: Yes, that's right: as a subject, *you* is **always** plural for purposes of numeric concord with the verb it governs. *I was, thou wert, he was, we were, you were, they were*.